# How to updating records in telerik gridview?

Tags: telerik

I want to use radcontrols for silverlight. Can I add,update and delete records in Radgridview itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can!  When you add or delete from a RADGridView, it will update the collection which you're binding to as your itemssource.  There are many ways to do it.  For instance, I don't want the RADGridView to remove an object from the collection when it deletes - so I shut that off.  What I do instead is make a context menu and when I "delete" I can either filter the item from the grid or change its color (so that I can "undelete" it). Then when I "save" my form, I go back to the WCF service to do the work.  Your model should have a status which could be enumerated such as:

- new
- dirty
- deleted
- unchanged

Your WCF service (we like SOA right?) then handles the status and does what it needs to do.  Your save should query your collection and only send those that are not "unchanged" back to the service.